# File content to single JSON string value with bash

Tags: json, bash, escaping

I would like to read a file and put the whole content into a single string that is escaped to be used in a JSON object.

And I want to do it on the commandline/terminal (Linux).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

### Version 1

WARNING: With this solution the content of the file can be too big to fit in an argument!

```
jq  -n                                \
   --arg content "$(cat theFile.txt)" \
   '{ theContent : $content }'        \
|                                     \
jq '.theContent'
```

### Version 2

[Jeff Mercado](https://stackoverflow.com/users/390278/jeff-mercado) provided a more compact solution for the first part - so I adapted that in my code as follows:

```
jq -Rs                  \
   '{ theContent: . }'  \
   theFile.txt          \
|                       \
jq '.theContent'
```

### Version 3

Now [Jeff Mercado](https://stackoverflow.com/users/390278/jeff-mercado) provided a more compact solution for what I was looking for:

```
jq -Rs '.' theFile.txt
```

Comment: Wait, so what's the point of putting it in the object if you're just going to pull it out later on? Is the whole goal here to just take the file and escape it as a json string only? If that's the case, you can skip the object and just output the result directly. `jq -Rs '.' theFile.txt`

Comment: Can you please consider to remove the "version 1" solution or put a warning ? With this solution the content of the file can be too big to fit in an argument: `bash: /usr/bin/jq: Argument list too long`. Corner case that can cause some issues ;)

Answer (score 11):

A more direct way to do that is to use the raw input (`-R`) combined with slurp (`-s`) parameters to read the entire input as a single string. Then take that input and store in the appropriate property. You don't need to pass it in as a separate parameter.

```
$ jq -Rs '{ theContent: . }' theFile.txt
```