# Curl POST gitlab API gives 404

Tags: rest, curl, post, gitlab, gitlab-api

I am trying to push a file to my folder called "collections" in my repository using curl.
 I've spent almost 2 days investigating problem and I am not sure what is the exact problem.

```
curl -D- -k -X GET -H "PRIVATE-TOKEN: faNFKoC4-opiDJ0FJSk" https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/592/repository/tree?path=collections
```

Get request works properly and I get list of files in collections folder.
The collections folder is a folder in my gitlab repository
But when I try to POST a file to that exact same folder I get 404:

```
curl -D- -k -X POST -H "PRIVATE-TOKEN: faNFKoC4-opiDJ0FJSk" -F "file=@C:/Documents/Folder_A/bp30_QA.csv" https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/592/repository/tree?path=collections
```

Am I missing some parameter? also gitlab API didn't help me very much.

Edit: Solution from Bertrand Martel helped me solve the issue

Also for everyone on windows having trouble installing ***jq***

> jq is a lightweight and flexible command-line JSON processor.

Install choco: https://chocolatey.org/install

Open powershell as administrator and run:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process -Force; [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol -bor 3072; iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))
```

After installation, run:

```
choco install jq
```

Comment: Have you tried to put quotes around URL ? (good habits).

Comment: Yes I have, tnx for the advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To [create a new file](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/repository_files.html#create-new-file-in-repository) called `bp30_QA.csv` in the `collections` folder, you can use the following :

```bash
curl -H 'PRIVATE-TOKEN: YOUR_PRIVATE_TOKEN' \
     -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
     -d '{
        "branch": "master", 
        "author_email": "johndoe@gmail.com", 
        "author_name": "John Doe",
        "content": '"$(jq -Rs '.' bp30_QA.csv)"', 
        "commit_message": "create a new file"
    }' "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/592/repository/files/collections%2Fbp30_QA.csv"
```

It uses [jq](/questions/tagged/jq) to wrap the content of the file in a single JSON field (check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49795061/2614364))